# Update data when pressing submit in chartjs in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I'm creating a chart showing data in vuejs, I try to update `labels` again but still not working.

In `ChartjsComponentLineChart.vue` :

```
<script>
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Line,
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Object,
      default: null,
    },
    options: {
      type: Object,
      default: null,
    },
    plugins: {
      type: Array,
      default: null,
    },
    styles: {
      type: Object,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.data, this.options, this.plugins, this.styles)
  },
}
</script>
```

In **report.vue**

```
 <b-card-body>
    <chartjs-component-line-chart
      :height="400"
      :data="data"
      :options="options"
      :plugins="plugins"
    />
  </b-card-body>

 <b-button
    variant="primary"
    class="btn-tour-finish"
    @click="submitData"
    >Submit
</b-button>



data() {
  return: {
     data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [70, 95, 100, 120, 257, 271, 300, 321, 383, 450],
            label: "Supper",
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Report",
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
      },
  }
},
created() {
    this.data.labels = [1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020, 2025];
  },
methods: {
   submitData() {
     this.data.labels = [1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020, 2025, 2030];
  }
}
```

The chart worked. But when I click submit `(submitData())` the `labels` doesn't update. Is there a way to update the 'labels' when I click. Give me any ideas. Thanks

Comment: Please add all relevant code you are using, so in this case the most relevant piece, your `chartjs-component-line-chart` is missing. Without this it will be impossible to know why tis not working and will just be guesswork

Comment: @LeeLenalee I have updated the question.. Can you help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it successfully.In this way : `v-if="loaded"`

```
<b-card-body>
    <chartjs-component-line-chart
      v-if="loaded"
      :height="400"
      :data="data"
      :options="options"
      :plugins="plugins"
    />
  </b-card-body>

data() {
  return: {
     data: {
        loaded: false,
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [70, 95, 100, 120, 257, 271, 300, 321, 383, 450],
            label: "Supper",
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Report",
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
      },
  }
},
created() {
    this.data.labels = [1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020, 2025];
    this.loaded = true;
  },
methods: {
   submitData() {
     this.data.labels = [1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020, 2025, 2030];
     this.loaded = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Chart.js itself is not reactive, you need to call the `update` method yourself when the data is changed. This behaviour of being non reactive out of the box is being taken over by vue-chartjs.

To make it reactive you need to add the `reactiveProp` mixin to your lineChart component according to the [docs](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts).

```js
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['options'],
  mounted () {
    // this.chartData is created in the mixin.
    // If you want to pass options please create a local options object
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  }
}
```

You can also implement your own watcher and call the update method of chart.js yourself according to the [docs](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#own-watcher)

```js
watch: {
  data () {
    this.$data._chart.update()
  }
}
```

Comment: Missing required prop: "chartData" .. This is the error I got when I followed your suggestion.Can you tell me how to fix this error? Thanks

Comment: Should have been data since your prop is called data I guess

Comment: Yes I called: `:chart-data="data"` and it was successful.. But when I press submit, the labels still don't change?